# Unable to fetch parent element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have created a scraper using Python Selenium.
**Technology used:**Python,Selenium
When I run the scraper it has to fetch the parent element for all the elements in the webpage.
**eg:Button,Image**.
I am pasting the code below:

```js
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Description: The Python code below will search selenium in Google.
import time
import csv
import os


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#EVERYTIME CHANGE THE DRIVER PATH TO THE CHROME DRIVER FOR LATEST CHROME VERSION
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="D:\Scraper\chromedriver.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

contents = []

filePath = 'output1.csv'
# As file at filePath is deleted now, so we should check if file
# exists or not not before deleting them
if os.path.exists(filePath):
    os.remove(filePath)
else:
    print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")

f = open("output1.csv", "a+")
f.write("website," + "title," + "htmltag," + "type," + "id," + "classname," + "for," + "href," + "alt," + "type," + "src,"
+ "name," + "width," + "height," + "data-src,"+ 'inner-text,' + 'action,' + 'value,' + "\n")


file = open("inputLinks1.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
 inputlinks = ''.join(str(e) for e in row) #convert to string to solve the usb issue
 driver.get(inputlinks)
 get_title = driver.title
 with open('xpathtags.csv', 'rt') as cp2_csv:
            cp_url2 = csv.reader(cp2_csv)
            for row1 in cp_url2:
                print(row[0])
                (xtype, xpathtext) = row1[0].split(';') 
                print(xtype, xpathtext)
                contents.append(xtype)
                contents.append(xpathtext)
                elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpathtext)
                for elem in elems:
                    f = open('output1.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
                    f.write( inputlinks 
                        + "~ "+ get_title + "~ "  # title
                        + " "+ xtype + "~ "       #dom type - links, image, etc
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('type')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('id')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('class')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('for')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('href')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('alt')).strip() + '~ '                        
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('type')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('src')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('name')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('width')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('height')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('data-src')).strip() + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('innerText').strip()) + '~ '
                        + str(elem.get_attribute('action')).strip() + '~ '
                         + str(elem.get_attribute('value')).strip() + '~ '

                        + '|~'
                        + '\n')
                    parent_elem = elems.find_element_by_xpath('..')
                    print("Parent class attribute: " + parent_elem.get_attribute("class"))
                    f.close()  

file.close()
                  
f.close()  


driver.close()
```

I have added a xpathtags file which will fetch all the elements in the webpage.

```js
Link;//a[@href]
Button;//button
Image;//img
Heading1;//h1
Heading2;//h2
Heading3;//h3
Heading4;//h4
Div;//div
Span;//span
```

The inputLinks.csv file contain the links fetched by the crawler.

```js
https://www.flipkart.com
https://www.ebay.com
```

The output1.csv is a blank file.The **scraped** elements will get saved into this file

**Error:**

```
Link //a[@href]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 82, in <module>
    write_output(row)
  File "demo.py", line 77, in write_output
    parent_elem = elems.find_element_by_xpath('..')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line return the `list of the Elements`: `find_elements_`

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpathtext)
```

And while trying to find `parent` tag `class` you are passing a `list` not an `WebElement`.

```
parent_elem = elems.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

Replace this - `parent_elem = elems.find_element_by_xpath('..')` to

```
parent_elem = elem.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```